# "All your commas are belong to Array" and similar — is this grammar form "proper"?

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs

I've often come across "weird" sentences like, say, instead of:

> All of your commas belong to Array.

It writes:

> All your commas are belong to Array.

It's not just once or twice, I actually see it *all* the time.

Is this usage actually grammatical or is simply a joke grammar?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a variation on / reference to the ["All your base are belong to us"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) meme.

[image]

> "All your base are belong to us" [...] is a broken English phrase that became an Internet phenomenon or meme in 2000–2002. [...] The text comes from the opening cutscene of [...] the video game [*Zero Wing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Wing), which was poorly translated from Japanese.

Comment: h2g2 is generally better written than Wikipedia, so I always prefer to link there when possible. It has a good article on this subject at http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/h2g2/A19147205.

Comment: h2g2 is *"an unconventional guide to life, the universe, and everything", in the spirit of the fictional publication The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* - for those who were wondering. Personally, I wouldn't assign it much credibility.

Comment: Though it has many omissions and contains much that is apocryphal, or at least wildly inaccurate, h2g2 scores over the older, more pedestrian work in two important respects. First, the entries are slightly shorter; and second, the pages of h2g2 are generally free of eerie pictures of Jimmy Wales.

Comment: @JYelton, If you notice any errors, please let us know. Either tell me, and I'll pass it on, or post to http://bbc.co.uk/dna/h2g2/Feedback-Editorial. Unlike Wikipedia, nothing gets into the Edited Guide without passing through Peer Review. It's probably more reliable than the 'Pedia. Anyone can write about anything, but articles marked as "Edited Guide Entry" have been through a formal approval process and are pretty reliable.

Comment: (And, incidentally, just to be pedantic, h2g2 is older than Wikipedia.)

Comment: I've never arrived at h2g2 using search engines on the web, but frequently see first-page Wikipedia results. As to why, this sentence, from [Wikipedia's entry on the fictional guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(fictional)#Influence), explains: *"[h2g2]'s creation predates Wikipedia by two years, though several commentators have noted the similarities between Wikipedia and the Hitchhiker's Guide, particularly its wild variance in reliability and quality and its tendency to focus on topics of interest to its writers."*

Comment: h2g2/Wikipedia links of interest: [Is Wikipedia Reliable?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1976/43), [Slate 2005 article: *Galaxy Quest*](http://www.slate.com/id/2117942/)