# How is "all your data are belong to US" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“All your commas are belong to Array” and similar — is this grammar form “proper”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25741/all-your-commas-are-belong-to-array-and-similar-is-this-grammar-form-proper)

What's the necessity of "are" before "belong" in this sentence?

> All your data are belong to US.

I don't understand the point of using "are" before "belong" here. Isn't it just fine to say: *all your data belong to US*?

[image: The well-known image of Uncle Sam (a white-haired man with a goatee, wearing a white top hat with white stars around the blue band, navy blue dinner jacket, and red bow tie) pointing his finger at the viewer. The (red and blue) text at the bottom says "All YOUR data are belong to US".]

Comment: Shouldn't that really be "all YOUR datum are belong to US"?

Answer (score 15):

It's *not* correct.  The image you have there was made to be tongue-in-cheek (at the expense of the US government). It's a play on the meme *[All your base are belong to us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)*.

As you say, if you remove the *are*, it becomes grammatical:

> All your data belong to us (or US, depending how you look at it).

Comment: You mean it's intentionally incorrect just for the sake of being humorous?

Comment: Yes.  It could easily be referring to [SOPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_Online_Piracy_Act) and [PIPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PROTECT_IP_Act), acts which were proposed this year which would essentially allow the government to become more and more invasive.

Comment: Actually, it is intentionally incorrect because it is an accidentally incorrect in the original meme. It has to put this way to reflect the meme properly.

Answer (score 6):

A little history is in order here.  This poster builds on the "All your base are belong to us" meme that arose from a poorly translated (from Japanese?) phrase in a video game in which the AI bad guys taunt the player that "we now have taken possession of all your bases".  See [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

It is ungrammatical, and you're right. *All your data belong to us* is correct.

There is a question of whether *data* might be treated as singular or plural. It's strictly a a plural noun, but often treated as singular (*All your data belongs to us*)

Comment: It is ungrammatical but perfectly fine for the context, as the other answers explained.